# enqueued script with jquery dependency not getting jquery

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

Adding scripts for my theme and added jquery as a dependency. I see the jquery script tag in the header of the page but my script in the footer is getting a "$ is not a function" error.

```
function wpdocs_template_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizer', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js', null, null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/main.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_template_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `.js` file

```
(function($) {
 // Your code inside here;
})(jQuery);
```

This is called an anonymous function, you're passing the jQuery object as a parameter to it.

**OR**

```
   var $ = jQuery; // This at the top of the file
```

This is simple, you're just assigning the `jQuery` object to the `$` variable

References:

[is-not-a-function-jquery-error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931680/6630308)

[jquery-is-not-a-function-error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109983/6630308)